# Как сократить код, чтобы не писать несколько раз if

Tags: java, android, if, android-button

```
Button button1, button2, button3;
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
if (button1.getText().equals("apple")) {
    button1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apple));
}
if (button1.getText().equals("bread")) {
    button1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bread));
}
if (button1.getText().equals("cheese")) {
    button1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cheese));
}
if (button2.getText().equals("apple")) {
    button2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apple));
}
if (button2.getText().equals("bread")) {
    button2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bread));
}
if (button2.getText().equals("cheese")) {
    button2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cheese));
}
if (button3.getText().equals("apple")) {
    button3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apple));
}
if (button3.getText().equals("bread")) {
    button3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bread));
}
if (button3.getText().equals("cheese")) {
    button3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cheese));
}
```

Comment: пишешь один метод void, в него передаешь кнопку и стрингу, которую проверяешь, пишешь в методе один такой if, в нем проверяешь пришедшую кнопку на наличие в тексте стринги, если ок, с помощью рефлекции по стринге получаешь нужный R.drawable и делаешь button.setBackground()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
switch(ВыражениеДляСравнения) {

    case Совпадение1: 
        команда;
        break;
    case Совпадение2: 
        команда;
        break;
    case Совпадение3: 
        команда;
        break;
    default: 
        оператор;
        break;
}
```

Так будет выглядеть в вашем случае:

```
private void checkText(Button button){
    //Смысл в том, что в оператор switch передается некое значение в скобки
    switch(button.getText()){
        //Которое затем отыскивается в операторе case, и выполняется некоторая логика. Подробнее об операторе можете посмотреть в ссылке.
        case "apple":
        button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apple));
        break;
        case "bread":
        button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bread));
        break;
        case "cheese":
        button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cheese));
        break;
    }

}
```

[Источник](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/switch.php)

Comment: никак не могу понять как реализовать

Comment: не могли бы подсказать новичку

Comment: @DeveloperChingis сейчас обновлю ответ

Comment: @DeveloperChingis получилось?

Comment: ошибку не показывает, но почему-то не работает

Answer (score 7):

Для этого нам понадобится заранее подготовленное отображение текста в имя ресурса (или чего там на самом деле):

```
public static final Map<String, String> M = new HashMap<>() {{
    put("chees", R.drawable.chees);
    put("apple", R.drawable.apple);
    ...
}};
```

И...

```
button1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(M.get(button1.getText())));
button2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(M.get(button2.getText())));
button3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(M.get(button3.getText())));
```

`M` показал статичным, предполагая, что `R.drawable.*` тоже статичные. Иначе `M` должен быть "обычным".

Зачем нам `if`, зачем не менее ужасный `switch`, когда в нашем распоряжении прекрасные коллекции java, которые как нельзя лучше подходят для этой не сложной  задачи?

Comment: почему-то вылетает

Comment: Мне отсюда не видно почему:(

Comment: button1.getText() ошибка здесь

Comment: Какая там ошибка? NullPointerException? Значит кнопка button1 == null. Больше ничего предположить не могу. Ваша кнопка, смотрите что с ней не так.

Answer (score 4):

Практически в любом языке есть такой оператор как switch:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 2):

Ну и мой вариант на тему switch.

Подмечаем, что фон является функцией от строки. Создаём такую функцию Drawable = f(String), использующую наш любимый switch для достижения своей цели:

```
private Drawable getBackground(String text) {
    if (text == null) return null; // или throw new IllegalArgumentException
    switch (text) {
        "apple" : return getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apple);
        "chees" : return getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chess);
        ...
    }
};
```

И далее смело используем её совершенно естественным образом:

```
button1.setBackground(getBackground(button1.getText()));
button2.setBackground(getBackground(button2.getText()));
button3.setBackground(getBackground(button3.getText()));
```

Comment: Надо ли говорить, что теперь можно крутить реализацию функцию как угодно, оставляя код установки фона естественным и "чистым"? Можно в реализации вместо switch использовать map, и даже if не будет казаться столь ужасным.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

```
Button button1, button2, button3;
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

switch (button1.getText()) {
    case "apple":
        button1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apple));
        break;
    case "bread":
        button1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bread));
        break;
    case "cheese":
        button1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cheese));
        break;
}
switch (button2.getText()) {
    case "apple":
        button2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apple));
        break;
    case "bread":
        button2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bread));
        break;
    case "cheese":
        button2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cheese));
        break;
}
switch (button3.getText()) {
    case "apple":
        button3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apple));
        break;
    case "bread":
        button3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bread));
        break;
    case "cheese":
        button3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cheese));
        break;
}
```

P.S. не совсем короче получается, поэтому можете вынести это в отдельную функцию:

```
public void switchButton(Button button) {
    switch (button.getText()) {
        case "apple":
            button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apple));
            break;
        case "bread":
            button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bread));
            break;
        case "cheese":
            button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cheese));
            break;
    }
}
```

И использовать её:

```
Button button1, button2, button3;
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

switchButton(button1);
switchButton(button2);
switchButton(button3);
```

Comment: А чем ваш ответ отличается от предложенного Asgard?

Comment: @gil9red ответ начинался писаться, когда ни одного ответа к посту ещё не было.

Comment: @Denis покажите ответ, для динамического получения значения `drawable`. Как показано [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856260/how-can-i-convert-string-to-drawable).

Comment: @Denis  ошибок нет, но изображении не показывает

Answer (score 0):

так не сканает?

```
button1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable[button1.getText()]))
button2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable[button2.getText()]))
button3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable[button3.getText()]))
```