# Как лучше поступить с checkbox и radiobutton если много условий

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста у меня в веб-части есть 10 чекбоксов и 5 радио-баттон, нужно написать роли типа if/else, но я поститал, что кода будет очень прилично количество, т.е. в каждый чекбокс нужно описать условия для других, т.к. они взаимосвязаны, а теперь вопрос как упростить это написание или например использовать другие методы или фреймворки? подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Использовать react?

Comment: Qwertiy, а можно пример привести и если реально покажите в чем его приемущество?

Comment: Описывал нечто подобное, правда на android. Идею думаю поймете: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593822/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-if/593827#593827

Comment: Asgard, через switch/case, попробуйю и отпишусь, спасибо за идею.

Comment: Asgard, пиши  оф.ответ, спасибо очень помог, через switch/case, очень все быстро сделал, респект )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения своей задачи меня полностью устроил switch/case.